# how to install packages inside virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv created for a Django project. Inside this project I have app folder with 'views.py'.

I have installed beautiful soup and requests inside this virtualenv and they import correctly into the 'views.py'.

However, for testing puroposes I have another script created inside the same folder as 'views.py' but when I try to import same modules there I get 'no module named...' error.

Virtualenv pip freeze looks like that:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.0.3
idna==2.6
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2018.3
requests==2.18.4
selenium==3.10.0
urllib3==1.22
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import webbrowser
import requests, bs4
import re
from .forms import RoomForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
#~ #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#~ # Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('PPPPPPOOOOOOOOSSSSSSSTTTTTTT')
        form = RoomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('VAAAALLLLLLIIIIIIDDDDDDDD')
            global form_data
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect('results')
    else:
        print('GGGGEEEEEETTTTT')
        form = RoomForm()


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'javascript/index.html', context)

def results(request):
    print(request.method)
    city = form_data['city'].title()
    print(city)
    prices = []
    real_prices = []
    url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/' + city +'--Hiszpania/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=' + city + '%2C%20Hiszpania&checkout=2018-04-22&children=0&infants=0&adults=2&guests=2&allow_override%5B%5D=&price_max=252&room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home%2Fapt&min_beds=0&s_tag=Ph6ohhjw'
    webbrowser.open(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_text = response.text
    airbnb_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response_text)
    page_selectors = airbnb_soup.select('._1bdke5s')
    print(len(page_selectors))
    last_page_selector = page_selectors[len(page_selectors) - 1]##############-15
    last_page_selector = last_page_selector.getText()
    for x in range(0, int(last_page_selector)):
        response = requests.get(url + '&section_offset=' + str(x))
        response_text = response.text
        airbnb_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response_text)
        spans = airbnb_soup.select('._hylizj6 span')
        for i in range(0, len(spans)):
            prices.append(spans[i].getText())
        for price in prices:
            if 'zł' in price:
                real_prices.append(price)
    real_prices.sort()
    print(real_prices)
    #print(real_prices)
    context = {'response_text': response_text, 'airbnb_soup': airbnb_soup,'spans': spans, 'real_prices': real_prices}
    return render(request, 'javascript/results.html',context)
```

How do I make those modules import correctly?

EDIT: I commented out everything in my 'views.py' except `import bs4, requests` and I get the same error. However they both work fine when my app is run on the development server.

Comment: "Is that possible?" - well, since you _are_ running into this problem now, that's possible... What's your question?

Comment: You should paste the output of 'pip freeze' in your question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Miprog, added now.

Comment: It looks like neither requests nor beautifulsoup are missing in your virtualenv. You should try to run the recursive install again to see if anything's missing somehow, and if that doesn't do it,  check that you aren't misspelling the names when you try to import them.

Comment: I am not mispelling them for sure. Strange they work fine for the 'views.py' inside the same folder...

Comment: so you are saying that you have two `views.py` under same folder, check the path for both the files. Also can you post the code here?

Comment: bhansa, no, I have only one views.py and another test.py file for testing.

Comment: Does it only work in `views.py` on the development server? If so, you're probably running the development server with the virtualenv python and the `test.py` script without it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I thought that since the packages are installed in this virtualenv, any script run inside this env can access those packages.. Isn't it so?

Comment: @barciewicz Yes, but just to be clear, what do you mean by "inside this env"? You need to activate it or use the full path to the python executable. My hypothesis was that you're running the development server with the correct interpreter but not activating it when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

save requirements to file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

activate virtualenv:

```
source /path/to/env/bin/activate
```

install packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in your .py file you want to import, use:

```
from . import beautifulsoup
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get 'requirements already satisfied' message and the problem still persists.

Comment: is it beautiful soup that is not loading?

Comment: Both requests and bs4 actually.